# How to generate html controls as per rows in table using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Iam developing Application using Asp.Net MVC3, i need create view as per database table rows.

Ex: Table have 1 column having 5 records(Rows). So now my application View should show those 5 records(Rows) as Html textbox Controls.
How to do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as "controls" in MVC, like there are controls in webforms.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **model** that maps on your database table, so for example

```
public class YourModel()
{
     public int ColumnName { get; set; }
}
```

Create a strong typed **view** that uses `IEnumerable<YourModel>` as model

Inside that view you can then do

```
@foreach(var row in Model)
{
    @Html.Textboxfor(row)
}
```

In your **controller** fill an `IEnumerable<YourModel>` from the database, and call the view like `return view(IEnumerable<YourModel>)`

This is pretty basic stuff, so if you already have trouble with this, I'd suggest you to read some MVC3 tutorials, or a book about it (eg: Pro ASP .NET MVC 3 Framework)